# Get Items from View of an Extrenal List(BCS List) programmatically

Tags: bcs, external-list, custom-bcs

I have created a external content type (BCS list) in SharePoint. I am using the below code in order to get items from bcs list.

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='BdcIdentity'/></IsNotNull></Where>";
SPListItemCollection col = list.GetItems(query);
```

Also I have created a view for the list. Can anyone tell me how to get items from the view of the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the Query Attribute of your View to include your Query, instead of retreiving the elements yourself with the SPQuery

```
<Query>
  <Where>
     <IsNotNull>
         <FieldRef Name='BdcIdentity'/>
     </IsNotNull>
  </Where>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="SOMEFIELDTOORDERBY"/>
  </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use the column name of the list.

Going through the list:

```
 foreach (SPListItem item in col)
 {
     Object o = item["column name"];
 }
```